# Rename some Tables to Table Name + DDMMYYYY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am importing some tables from one SQL Server to another, every night and the table should have a `DDMMYYYY` sufix at the destination. I could not think of a way to change the name during import process and thought of renaming it after import. I am stuck here too as I am not able to get `SP_RENAME` to work in the format `SP_RENAME 'TABLE_NAME' 'TABLE_NAME+DDMMYYYY'`.

Comment: Instead of making copies of tables daily, have you considered adding a date column and keeping all of the data in a single table? When data is split up in many tables, it becomes difficult to query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, it really sounds like you should be loading this tables on one table and use another column for storing the date. Nevertheless, you could use dynamic SQL for what you want:

```
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(8), @Table NVARCHAR(500), @Query NVARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)
SET @Table = 'TABLE_NAME'
SET @Query = 'EXEC sp_rename '''+@Table+''','''+@Table+@Date+''''

EXEC(@Query)
```

Oh, and take a look at [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to read about dynamic SQL on SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was looking for. This fits in my requirement where I am automating the whole thing to run without any manual intervention.

Comment: @nirajkumar: In this case, a simpler solution would be: `EXEC sp_rename 'MySchema.OldTableName','NewTableName20130722','OBJECT'` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean ?, it would be a simpler solution that hard codes the date, and that wasn't what was asked

Comment: @Lamak: +1 Yep. Agree.

Answer (score 2):

Execute this script in SQL Server Management Studio **(`Ctrl+T` (Text Output), `F5` (Execute))** to generate another `T-SQL` script:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,@EndDate DATETIME;
SELECT  @StartDate='2013-07-10T00:00:00',
        @EndDate='2013-07-23T00:00:00';

PRINT 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;'

SELECT  'EXEC sp_rename '
        +''''
        +QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(t.name)
        +''','''
        +QUOTENAME(t.name+STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),t.create_date,103),3,1,''),5,1,''))
        +''', ''OBJECT'''
FROM    sys.tables t
JOIN    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id=s.schema_id
WHERE   t.create_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
--AND   t.name LIKE '%pattern%'

PRINT 'ROLLBACK;'
PRINT '-- COMMIT;'

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```

Example output/script generated (`Message panel`):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[NodesOrder]','[NodesOrder19072013]'
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[RateTable]','[RateTable19072013]'
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[A]','[A22072013]'
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo2].[A]','[A22072013]'
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[ConstraintTest]','[ConstraintTest17072013]'
ROLLBACK;
-- COMMIT;
```

Now, execute this script (`Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+V`, `F5`).